# Separating numbers (in a single line array) with more than 2 digits into several columns

Tags: arrays, sorting, matlab, vector, digit

Is there a way to separate

```
`vector=[0345;0230;0540;2340]`
```

into

```
`vec_1=[03;02;05;23]`
```

and

```
`vec_2=[45;30;40;40]`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
v = [0345;0230;0540;2340];
vv = num2str(v,'%04d');    %# convert to strings, 4 digits, fill with zeros
v1 = str2num( vv(:,1:2) )  %# extract first two digits, convert back to number
v2 = str2num( vv(:,3:4) )  %# extract last two digits, convert back to number
```

The result:

```
v1 =
     3
     2
     5
    23
v2 =
    45
    30
    40
    40
```

Of course, if you want the result as a cell-array of strings (with any leading zeros kept), use:

```
>> v1 = cellstr(num2str(v1,'%02d'))
v1 = 
    '03'
    '02'
    '05'
    '23'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
vector=[0345;0230;0540;2340]; 
v1 = mod(vector,100)
(vector-v1)/100
```